# decode cookie data as json on controller side

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm receiving on mvc4 razor view cookie. looking on firebug I can see cookie raw data and json formatted data.

I've found that on razor side this should work

```
@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(object))
```

How can I on controller side decode raw cookie data to json to examine further.

Is there something like

```
Json.Encode(Request.Cookies["MyCookie"].Value); // this doesnt work
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [**Newtonsoft.Json**](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to convert JSON back and forth; it works great.

You can decode a cookie using below pattern:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Request.Cookies["MyCookie"].Value);
```

*Note:*
If you encoded a value and stored it in a cookie, you must decode it before deserilizing. `HTTPUtility.UrlDecode()` could be used to decode encoded values.

Hope this help.

Comment: I'm receiving error - Additional information: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: %. Path '', line 0, position 0.

Comment: I tried also var JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Request.Cookies["MyCookie"].Value.ToString());

Comment: check what exactly is contained in your cookie as value(check if it's JSON or not!)

Comment: I'm receiving data as value not as json, on firebug tab I have value, raw and json. I want as json but I'm getting as value.

Comment: you need to check it on **server**- what value is being posted in that cookie!

Comment: @user1765862 It is probably a problem related to encoding or escaping the value before storing it in a cookie. This means that it should be decoded (Inscaped) before deserializing.